# How to add two values using similar syntax in Excel function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, excel-2010, vba

Look:

```
C:C=A:A+B:B
```

This will ADD the values of Ai+Bi in Ci

The question is how to the same using the function way:

```
C:C=SUM(A:A:B:B)
```

How I need to write it to get it work!

Thanks

Comment: What is it that you need? It's not clear from your question. Can you provide an example of what you've done so far?

Comment: I need to do the same operation using the function ADD not the + operator. How to do that with the same result.

Comment: There is no `ADD` function in Excel. Do you need `SUM`? Why is the `+` operator not sufficient?

Comment: ok SUM... that's an example... not ADD is SUM .. excuse me

Comment: =SUM(A1:B1) and fill down.

Answer (score 0):

Stab in the dark:

```
=SUM(A:A+B:B)
```

entered with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.